# How to use keyboard shortcuts in textInput?

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to use keyboard shortcuts like `Alt + -` for `<-` and `Ctrl + Shift + M` for %>% in a textInput in shiny. I'm not sure where to start or how to use javascript to add this feature. I came across this [keys](https://r4fun.github.io/keys/) package which may help. I'm also trying to see if this could be used in the `shinyAce` package with the `aceEditor` function.

Code

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("caption", "Caption", "Data Summary"),
  verbatimTextOutput("value")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$value <- renderText({ input$caption })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Those (specific shortcuts) aren't shiny, they aren't even standard across IDEs. Unless I'm mistaken, that's an RStudio thing, not a `shiny` thing.

Comment: Yes, I would like to use RStudio shortcuts in shiny.

Comment: The RStudio IDE is not written in `shiny`, nor is it written in `R`. I don't know how they do it, I think your only bet for knowing for sure is to look within their [source code](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/) and find it there, or ask them specifically.